# Three-tier Multi-Level Model: violation of the assumptions of normality and heteroscedasticity

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, multilevel-analysis

I am working with educational data. To do so, I am using the classic three-level hierarchical linear model (student, class and school).
I am using the R software lmer package and the stata software.
When I perform the residual analysis, the assumptions of homoscedasticity and normality are not met.
Here is the adjusted model:
**m33 <- lmer(pt_ex ~ gen_alun + rep_alun + comp_alun + educ_ee + gen_prof + idad_prof + nro_alun_turm + sase_esc + reg_esc + area_esc + (1|id_esc) + (1|id_turm), REML = T, date = data)**

Comments:

1. The dependent variable pt_ex (Exam Score) despite being continuous, has only discrete values ​​(0 to 100).
2. Regarding the independent variables, with the exception of the variable nro_alun_turm (Number of students in the class), these are nominal/binary categorical.

I thought of using a GLM, namely a Poisson or Negative Binomial multilevel model, but these have infinite support. So, could you try a Gamma, since the two assumptions of the Gaussian model were not met?

thanks in advance,

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nffjA.png
```

[image]
[image: graph Q-Q]
[image: graph histogram]
[image: graph residuals levels 1,2 and 3]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: close enough to a normal

Comment: I disagree with @Germania. The distribution is not close to Normal as it's not symmetric. For some perspectives on the effect of skewness see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204585/independent-samples-t-test-do-data-really-need-to-be-normally-distributed-for-l).