# Sample size calculation: z or t

Tags: sample-size

I am confused about what I've seen in my textbook to calculate the sample size for a specified confidence interval width (for a mean).

The book says whether you know $\sigma$ or have $S$ from a previous study, you can use

$$z_{\alpha /2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}=x$$

where $x$ is half the width of the interval.

What doesn't make sense to me is that if you use that formula using a value $S$ instead of $\sigma$, shouldn't you be using a $t$ value instead of $z$? Which requires $n$ itself, but maybe you could use an iterative method where you choose an initial $n$ and keep updating the value of $t$ until convergence.

The reason I think $t$ should be used is because when you actually go and collect your data, you will be constructing the interval with $\bar{Y} \pm t_{\alpha/2,n-1}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$, so if you used $z$ to calculate the sample you probably won't end up with the correct width, will you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update*: @Paje points out that the theory behind the computations assumes that the population is normally distributed; when normality is violated the theory doesn't hold exactly. It's an important point but keep in mind that "*not exact*" doesn't necessarily mean "*wrong*"; it means "*approximate*". The relevant question is: Is the normality assumption reasonably satisfied to justify my analysis? So for fun, I've updated the simulation to sample from a) the normal; b) the Laplace distribution which is symmetric, with heavier tails than the normal; c) the log-normal which is skewed to the right.

---

*Terminology*: The half-width of a confidence interval is known as its margin of error. I'll use "margin" and "half-width" interchangeably.

It seems that by "end up with the correct width" you mean that the half-width of the confidence interval is exactly $\operatorname{margin}$ if we calculate the sample size $n$ to achieve margin of error $\operatorname{margin}$. Not quite.

If we have an accurate estimate $\hat{\sigma}$ of the true standard deviation $\sigma$, then we don't need to estimate $\sigma$ from the experimental data. We can plug in $\hat{\sigma}$ in the formula for the confidence interval and the margin of error $z_{\alpha/2}\hat{\sigma}/\sqrt{n}$ is fixed.

If we decide to estimate $\sigma$ with the sample standard deviation $s$, then the margin of error is $t_{\alpha/2,n-1}s/\sqrt{n}$ as you point out. And since $s$ is a random variable, it can be either smaller or bigger than $\sigma$. In other words, if we repeat the experiment with the same sample size $n$, the margin of error $t_{\alpha/2,n-1}s/\sqrt{n}$ will vary from replication to replication because $s$ varies. It's never going to be *exactly* equal to $\operatorname{margin}$.

What matters is that the coverage of the confidence interval is $100(1-\alpha)$% under the null hypothesis, ie, if the null hypothesis is true and we repeat the experiment many times, 95% of the confidence intervals thus constructed will contain the true mean. As long as the "known" $\hat{\sigma}$ is an accurate estimate of the true standard deviation $\sigma$ and the distribution is not asymmetric, the sample size calculation $n \approx (z_{\alpha/2}\hat{\sigma}/\operatorname{margin})^2$ results in (approximately) correct coverage for the $z$ and $t$ confidence intervals. The approximation gets better with larger sample size ⇔ smaller margin of error.

| distribution | mean | std.dev | margin | n | z_coverage | z_lower | z_upper | t_coverage | t_lower | t_upper |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| normal | 0 | 1 | 0.50 | 17 | 0.9498 | 0.0264 | 0.0238 | 0.9456 | 0.0268 | 0.0276 |
| laplace | 0 | 1.41 | 0.50 | 33 | 0.9564 | 0.0202 | 0.0234 | 0.9544 | 0.0218 | 0.0238 |
| lognormal | 1.65 | 2.16 | 0.50 | 76 | 0.9560 | 0.0060 | 0.0380 | 0.9146 | 0.0818 | 0.0036 |
| normal | 0 | 1 | 0.10 | 404 | 0.9598 | 0.0212 | 0.0190 | 0.9568 | 0.0224 | 0.0208 |
| laplace | 0 | 1.41 | 0.10 | 808 | 0.9588 | 0.0212 | 0.0200 | 0.9538 | 0.0246 | 0.0216 |
| lognormal | 1.65 | 2.16 | 0.10 | 1886 | 0.9562 | 0.0160 | 0.0278 | 0.9476 | 0.0358 | 0.0166 |
| normal | 0 | 1 | 0.05 | 1615 | 0.9530 | 0.0254 | 0.0216 | 0.9488 | 0.0274 | 0.0238 |
| laplace | 0 | 1.41 | 0.05 | 3229 | 0.9562 | 0.0216 | 0.0222 | 0.9496 | 0.0252 | 0.0252 |
| lognormal | 1.65 | 2.16 | 0.05 | 7541 | 0.9520 | 0.0216 | 0.0264 | 0.9404 | 0.0366 | 0.0230 |

---

R code to calculate the sample size using the normal approximation $n \approx (z_{\alpha/2}\hat{\sigma}/\operatorname{margin})^2$ and then estimate the coverage of the $z$ and $t$ confidence intervals for the mean.

```r
# the true mean and standard deviation
mu_true <- 0
sigma_true <- 1

# the coverage of the confidence intervals should be 100(1-alpha) = 95%
alpha <- 0.05

calculate_sample_size <- function(margin, known_sigma) {
  # Use the normal approximation to choose the sample size
  z_alpha <- qnorm(1 - alpha / 2)
  ceiling((z_alpha * known_sigma / margin)^2)
}

estimate_std_dev <- function(sigma) {
  # How accurate is the "known" standard deviation?
  # Let's assume it is 2.5% higher than true std. deviation.
  sigma * 1.025
}

get_moments <- function(distribution = c("normal", "laplace", "lognormal")) {
  if (distribution == "lognormal") {
    # The log-normal distribution is not symmetric;
    # it's skewed to the right.
    mu_pop <- exp(mu_true + sigma_true^2 / 2)
    sd_pop <- sqrt((exp(sigma_true^2) - 1) * exp(2 * mu_true + sigma_true^2))
  } else if (distribution == "laplace") {
    # The Laplace distribution is symmetric, with mean = location
    # and variance = 2 * scale^2.
    mu_pop <- mu_true
    sd_pop <- sqrt(2) * sigma_true
  } else {
    mu_pop <- mu_true
    sd_pop <- sigma_true
  }
  c(mu_pop, sd_pop)
}

coverage <- function(n, distribution = c("normal", "laplace", "lognormal")) {
  distribution <- match.arg(distribution)

  if (distribution == "lognormal") {
    x <- rlnorm(n, meanlog = mu_true, sdlog = sigma_true)
  } else if (distribution == "laplace") {
    x <- VGAM::rlaplace(n, location = mu_true, scale = sigma_true)
  } else {
    x <- rnorm(n, mean = mu_true, sd = sigma_true)
  }

  xbar <- mean(x)

  mean_stddev <- get_moments(distribution)
  mu_pop <- mean_stddev[1]
  sd_pop <- mean_stddev[2]

  sd_known <- estimate_std_dev(sd_pop)

  z_alpha <- qnorm(1 - alpha / 2)
  t_alpha <- qt(1 - alpha / 2, df = n - 1)

  c(
    abs(xbar - mu_pop) < z_alpha * sd_known / sqrt(n),
    mu_pop > xbar + z_alpha * sd_known / sqrt(n),
    mu_pop < xbar - z_alpha * sd_known / sqrt(n),

    abs(xbar - mu_pop) < t_alpha * sd(x) / sqrt(n),
    mu_pop > xbar + t_alpha * sd(x) / sqrt(n),
    mu_pop < xbar - t_alpha * sd(x) / sqrt(n)
  )
}

calculate_coverage <- function(margin_of_error, distribution) {

  mean_stddev <- get_moments(distribution)
  true_mean <- mean_stddev[1]
  true_stddev <- mean_stddev[2]
  known_stddev <- estimate_std_dev(true_stddev)

  sample_size <- calculate_sample_size(margin_of_error, known_stddev)

  nreps <- 5000
  stats <- rowMeans(replicate(nreps, coverage(sample_size, distribution)))

  data.frame(
    "distribution" = distribution,
    "mean" = true_mean,
    "std dev" = true_stddev,
    "margin of error" = margin_of_error,
    "sample size" = sample_size,
    "z_coverage" = stats[1],
    "z_lower" = stats[2],
    "z_upper" = stats[3],
    "t_coverage" = stats[4],
    "t_lower" = stats[5],
    "t_upper" = stats[6]
  )
}

set.seed(12345)

rows <- data.frame()

for (margin in c(0.5, 0.1, 0.05)) {
  for (distribution in c("normal", "laplace", "lognormal")) {
    rows <- rbind(rows, calculate_coverage(margin, distribution))
  }
}

knitr::kable(rows, format = "pipe")
```

Answer (score 3):

On top of @dipetkov's great and detailed answer, a (not so) small warning : these confidence intervals are accurate and true **only** for Normally Distributed (independent) random variables, and approximately true for n sufficiently large (but how approximate and how large?).

**if** $\forall i,  X_i \sim  \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and independent **then** we have $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n X_i = \overline{X_n} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$$
So indead if we know in advance the std $\sigma$, a $1-\alpha$ CI of the mean estimation $\hat{\mu}$ is $\overline{x_n} \pm z_{\alpha/2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$. no limits here, and if you run simulations, fix an $n$, the average nb of experiments that ends with $\mu \in CI(x_1, ... x_n)$ will tend to **exactly** $1-\alpha$ when the nb of experiments tend to $\infty$. math here, no approximations.

When you don't know in advance the std $\sigma$ of your *normal* distribution, you use the Student distribution, which is, by definition, a random variable $\mathcal{T}_m$ ($m$ number of degrees of freedom) that has same law as a $ Z / \sqrt{U/m}$ when $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $U \sim \chi^2_m$. Math tells us that $$\sqrt{n}\Big(\frac{\overline{X_n} - \mu}{S_n}\Big) \sim \mathcal{T}_{n-1}$$
Hence the $1-\alpha$ CI for the estimator of $\mu$ : $\overline{x_n} \pm t_{\alpha/2,n-1} \frac{s_n}{\sqrt{n}}$. Again, this is true for all n, not just approximately true when n is large or anything

Now the warning : when $X$ does not have a Normal Distribution, these CI on the mean estimation are **wrong** : the probability of the real $\mathbb{E}[X]$ (if it exists! see Cauchy distributions for an example without it) being inside the CI computed on a particular experiment of n samples *is not* $1-\alpha$. Yes, the TCL says that when n tends to $\infty$, the r.v. $\sqrt{n}\frac{\overline{X_n} - \mu}{\sigma}$ converges in distribution to $ \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ but we don't actually know starting from what $n$ this approximation will be "almost true" (or at least negligeable to have almost $1-\alpha$ experiments ending with $\mu \in CI$. One usually says $n > 30$ as a rule of thumb, but be careful : try experiments for n = 100, $ X \sim \mathcal{B}(p)$ a Bernoulli distribution with variable $p$ between 0 and 1.
see [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-2/Interval-Estimation-for-a-Binomial-Proportion/10.1214/ss/1009213286.full) for detailed work, fun figure n°3. Do reproduce it at home.

Comment: Good point. The theory behind the $t$ confidence interval assumes the true distribution is Normal. The approximation will hold well as long as the distribution is symmetric/not skewed even if it's not exactly Normal. See also [Independent samples t-test: Do data really need to be normally distributed for large sample sizes?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204585/independent-samples-t-test-do-data-really-need-to-be-normally-distributed-for-l).