# How does the t-distribution arise from a sample that is not normally distributed and allows me to A/B test with the t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Assume I am having samples from an unknown distribution in group A and B. By computing the mean for each group on sufficiently large samples, I know that mu_A and mu_B are approximately normally distributed, with an unknown mean and variance.

Taking the difference of the two groups allows me to know that the mean of the normal distribution is zero. However, I still don't know the variance.

As I understood it, by computing the sample mean from samples that are **normally distributed** and normalizing them i get the t-value that follows the t-distribution. However, I only have one single sample that is normally distributed in my example above. What am i missing here?

Comment: "How does the t-distribution arise ...." -- it doesn't. (You can get asymptotic normality, which the t will also approximate and in practice often the t does fairly well as an approximation in smaller samples.)

Comment: Seems there is a possibility of confusion between 'sample' as a _collection_ of randomly sampled values (the generally accepted meaning in statistics) and 'sample' as one _individual_ observation (as used on some so called instructional online sites and even in some software--IMHO incorrectly).

Answer (score 3):

Let me show some established terminology and notation to try to clarify
what you are doing. There is nothing below that can't be found in a basic
statistics textbook, but I have chosen what to say, hoping specifically 
to clear up---in the most compact feasible way--some of the confusion in your question.

**Population parameters and estimates from a sample.** If $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m$ is a random sample of size $m$ from a Population A
with distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_A, \sigma_a),$ then the population mean $\mu_A$ is estimated
by the sample mean $\bar X = \frac 1m \sum_{i=1}^m X_i = \hat \mu_A.$

Also, the population variance
$\sigma_A^2$ is estimated by the sample variance $S_X^2 = \frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{i=1}^m (X_i - \bar X)^2  = \widehat{\sigma_A^2}.$

If the population variance $\sigma_A^2$ is known, then 
$$Z_A = \frac{\bar X_A - \mu_A}{\sigma_A/\sqrt{m}} \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$$
the standard normal distribution.

**One-sample tests.** If the population variance $\sigma_A^2$ is not known and is estimated by $S_X^2,$ then 
$$T_A = \frac{\bar X_A - \mu_A}{S_X/\sqrt{m}} \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu=m-1),$$
Student's t distribution with $m - 1$ degrees of freedom. If $m$ is very large, so that $S_X^2$ estimates $\sigma_A^2$ very closely, then the distribution 
$\mathsf{T}(\nu=m-1)$ is very closely approximated by $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$

The statistic $T_A$ can be used for one-sample tests and to make confidence intervals for $\mu_A,$ but your Question is about two-sample tests, so I will move on  to that.

Similar notation and results hold for a random sample $Y_1, Y_2, \dots Y_n$
from Population B distributed as $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_B, \sigma_B)$ and for
$Z_B \sim \mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ and $T_B \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu=n-1).$

**Two-sample tests.** Now, if you have samples from both populations and you want to test the
null hypothesis $H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B$ against the alternative $H_1: \mu_A \ne \mu_B,$ then the test statistic for a pooled two-sample (or A/B) test is
$$T = \frac{\bar X - \bar Y}{S_p\sqrt{\frac 1m + \frac 1n}} \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu = m+n-2),$$
where $S_p^2 = \frac{(m-1)S_X^2 + (n-1)S_Y^2}{m+m-2}.$ One would reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance, if $|T| \ge t_c,$ where $t_c$ cuts probability $0.05/2 = 0.025$ from the upper tail of the distribution $\mathsf{T}(\nu = m+n-2).$

This test is performed under the assumption that the two populations have
the same variance: $\sigma_A^2 = \sigma_B^2 = \sigma^2.$ The 'pooled variance estimate' $S_p^2$ shown above uses information from both samples to estimate
the common population variance $\sigma^2.$

If $m + n$ is very large, so that $S_p^2$ is nearly equal to $\sigma^2,$ then $T$ has nearly a standard normal distribution, so one might reject the null hypothesis if $|T| \ge 1.96.$

*Notes:* (1) Some elementary texts say that for testing at the 5% level of significance, 'very large' means something like $m + n > 30.$ One  argument is that for 28 degrees of freedom the 5% critical value is $t_c = 2.048,$ which rounds to $2.0,$ as does $1.96.$ Another is that, on a graph as below, it can be difficult to distinguish the density functions of $\mathsf{T}(28)$ (black) and standard normal (dotted red). However, by more precise computation, as @Glen_b comments, that approximation could actually mean testing at about the 6% level.

[image]

(2) *Unequal variances.* If we are unable to assume that $\sigma_A^2 = \sigma_B^2,$ then the
exact test statistic $T$ given above is incorrect and it is difficult to
find the exact distribution of $T.$ However, the Welch two-sample t test
uses a slightly different form of $T$ and a sufficiently accurate approximate
t distribution for most practical applications. Almost all of what I have shown you above still applies, but there is a little more to say. If you are interested in that, perhaps you can find a useful explanation in a statistics text or google 'Welch t test'.

(3) *Non-normal data.* If data are not normal, then you can hope sample sizes are large enough that sample means are nearly normal and that sample variances closely approximate population variances. Then the two sample $T$-statistic may be nearly normal. This may be useful if population distributions are not markedly skewed. You might search on this site and elsewhere for 'robustness of t tests against non-normal data'.

---

*Addendum: Numerical example.*  Here is output for a pooled t test from R statistical
software. $n = 12, m = 13,$ $X$'s from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_A=100,\sigma=10),$ $Y$'s from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_B=112, \sigma=10).$
Because this is a simulation, we know that the population means differ by $12,$ so we can hope the test detects this difference. Because $|T| = 2.28 > t_c = 2.07$ the null hypothesis is indeed rejected.

```
set.seed(708)   # for reproducibility
x = rnorm(12, 100, 10);  y = rnorm(13, 112, 10)
mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 102.466
[1] 65.76268
mean(y);  var(y)
[1] 111.3025
[1] 119.215
boxplot(x, y, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=19)
  points(c(mean(x), mean(y)), 1:2, col="red")  $ red circles show means
```

[image]

```
t.test(x, y, var.eq=T)

        Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -2.2809, df = 23, p-value = 0.03214
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -16.8505188  -0.8224146
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 102.4660  111.3025 

c.t = qt(.975, 23);  c.t
[1] 2.068658
```

Comment: Many people would not regard a test done at the 6% significance level an adequate approximation to a 5% test (especially not given many people complain about the efficiency of a Mann-Whitney test at the normal; you could completely reverse that difference if you're happy to call 6% "5%"). With m+n=30 we have:  `pt(1.96,30-2,lower.tail=FALSE)*2` 
`[1] 0.06001673`  ... (or it's 5.97% at m+n=31)

Comment: @Glen_b: Of course, you're right. Thanks. Cleaned this up a bit and moved it to the "Notes."  Will happily delete Note (1) if you think it's best not to try to be specific about speed of convergence to t to normal.

Comment: I don't mind you nominating a value if it's a bit closer to the nominal rate (personally I tend to be reasonably happy if a nominally 5% test is not out by more than half a percent, but many people tend to be a bit more strict) - even 30 is fine if you're explicit about how far off the significance level is. Better people know it and use it in full knowledge than not know it and presume it's close

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. However, you assume at the very beginning that X_1,...,X_n come from a Normal distribution. My question is, how and if at all the test works when i start with X_1,...,X_n from **any** distribution, as it is the case for most real world A/B test. The metrics like commision or number of transactions are usually highly skewed towards zero

Comment: If you will look in the margin at the right under 'Related' you'll find some pgs on this site about non-normal data for one and two sample t tests. Did you look?  Another is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/242037/robustness-of-the-student-t-test-to-non-gaussian-data). My answer is 'elaborate' because your Question seem to raise a variety of issues, including cases with normal data--and in a way that made me wonder if you understand the points I discussed. I think you need that information first. // Questions are easier to answer if they clearly focus on a single issue.

Comment: Sorry @BruceET, I did not want to offend you. I fully appreciate your elaborate answer, this was not meant to sound negative. It's a very illustrative and easy to understand explanation that you gave. Thank you also for the link, this is more what i was looking for, as the textbooks always just assume the variables are sampled from a normal distribution.